# Is it possible to break a hole in wall with weakeast object when thrown?

Tags: science-based

Is it possible to break a hole in wall with weakeast object when thrown ?

Like for a example a person with no magic power but with pure supernatural strength like superman or goku throws a pencile or pen in to the wall would be there a hole or the object its self won't able to handle  the strenth or speed when thrown.

Comment: Assuming you throw it fast enough, definitely, [yes](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/), well, asuming you consider a cloud of radioactive dust as a "hole"

Comment: Is is possible  to tear space itself then ?

Comment: What kind of wall are we talking about? Dry-wall? Concrete? Be specific.

Comment: How are you going to build a new fictional world with this information?

Comment: Note that there is a different between asking a science-based question and asking a science question. The latter is not appropriate for Worldbuilding SE.

Comment: Oh really!? Sorry then.

Comment: Please read [this section of Help Center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/asking) - basically, questions that are not asked for the purpose of building fictional worlds are off topic here.

Comment: @swswsws Obligatory xkcd: https://what-if.xkcd.com/39/ Also this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QfDoQwIAaXg&t=60s In short: you cannot make up for "weakness" with speed because that will have the opposite effect; even very tough and hard objects will behave like putty and "splash" when the speed is high enough. Slow and steady is the way to go if your material is "weak". This is why **plants** can break though asphalt and concrete.

Comment: If you have a completely new question, swswsws, please ask it as a new question, rather than editing an existing post of yours. I've rolled your edit back.

Comment: @HDE226868 well I no longer can ask new questions

Comment: @swswsws try to open a meta post to get help on what you can do to rectify this. Some users might be able to give you an idea to improve your existing questions and get them reopened. Slow down, and enjoy the weirdness of the WB community, while you learn what our scope is.

Answer (score 4):

There is *no limit* on how much damage a small light object can do if thrown fast enough. A pencil thrown at sufficiently close to light speed could destroy the Earth.

Comment: True, but you can't throw a pencil hard enough to _just_ punch a clean hole in the wall of a castle. By the time you get enough energy into the pencil to make an impression on a stone wall, you're talking major explosions.

Comment: @Deolater That is a fair point.

Comment: @Deolater 2by4s propelled by a hurricane can penetrate a cinder-block wall quite cleanly.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Agreed, but a 2x4 is an order of magnitude larger than a pencil, and a cinderblock wall an order of magnitude less than a castle wall. There are certain ranges of energies, momenta, and densities where Newtonian physics allow certain projectiles to penetrate certain barriers. This answer is saying that relativistic velocities allow _any projectile_ (if driven fast enough) to destroy _any barrier_. My point is simply  that this is true, but at some point you're talking about something more akin to atomic bombs than conventional projectiles.

Comment: There is a limit to how much damage something can do, since nothing with mass gets faster than the speed of light. Moreover the OP speaks about events happening inside the earths atmosphere, the pencil would get instantly obliterated when thrown with such force.

Comment: @r41n The limitation to the speed of light doesn't limit the kinetic energy, which is what matters. A pencil moving at exactly the speed of light would have infinite energy and destroy the entire universe (within its light cone).

Comment: @Deolater you can. https://youtu.be/3D-RkBnHE-A?t=76 15 gram plastic bullet against an aluminum target at about 3km/s speed. Throw harder.

Comment: @MikeScott that's the point, nothing with mass (like a pencil) can get to that speed, since that would require infinite energy in the first place. That's why there is an intrinsic limit.

Comment: @r41n But it can get as close as you want to the limit, if you pump in enough energy. There's no theoretical limit on the amount of kinetic energy it can have, so there's no limit on the amount of damage it can do.

Comment: @MikeScott you are actually right. Then again, at that point, having a pencil as a projectile doesn't matter anymore. You could just punch the air and have the same result, couldn't you?

Comment: @r41n Correct.  In such situations, the projectile is basically a directed energy weapon.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Newtons approximation of impact depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth), penetration depth D is roughly the Length of the projectile L multiplied by the ratio of material densities:

```
D=L*(A/B)
```

Note that this only holds for large velocities (higher than the speed of sound in the target, but still << c).

So, a pencil or pen are actually ideal projectiles, as they are very long and should be able to penetrate deeply in ordinary wall material. Of course, this only holds as long as the wall isn't hard enough to let the projectile simply [disintegrate on impact](https://youtu.be/QfDoQwIAaXg?t=1m5s).